# "Found interface scalaz.Tree, but class was expected" error while instantiating a Specification class

Tags: scala, scalaz

I successfully compile the following 2 scala files using:

```
scalac -classpath "../specs2_2.11-2.4.jar;../scalaz-core_2.10.0-M6-7.0.0-M2.jar;classes" -d classes *.scala
```

When I run:

```
scala -classpath "../specs2_2.11-2.4.jar;../scalaz-core_2.10.0-M6-7.0.0-M2.jar;classes" Chapter1.Introduction
```

I get

```
Is 'Herculaneum' a palindrome? false
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface scalaz.Tree, but class was expected
...
```

**val p = new IntroSpec** doesn't seem to work. I'd like to instantiate and run the **IntroSpec** class. How can I do it correctly? Thank you.

**Introduction.scala**

```
package JustTrying
import Chapter1.Introduction
import org.specs2.mutable._

class IntroSpec extends Specification {
  "The phrase 'Never odd or even'" should {
    "be a palindrome" in {
      Introduction.isPalindrome("Never odd or even") must beTrue
    }
  }
}
```

**IntroSpec.scala**

```
package Chapter1
import JustTrying.IntroSpec

object Introduction extends App {
  def isPalindrome(word: String) = {
    val modifiedWord = word.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[^a-z0-9]", "")
    val reversed = modifiedWord.reverse
    modifiedWord == reversed
  }
  println("Is 'Herculaneum' a palindrome? " + isPalindrome("Herculaneum"))
  val p = new IntroSpec
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a scala version conflict: specs2 uses scala 2.11 and scalaz uses scala 2.10.

Comment: I forgot to mention, my scala version is the latest i.e. 2.12.7 and the jdk is 9.0.4.

Comment: I've updated jars to
**specs2-core_2.12-4.3.5.jar &** scalaz-core_2.12-7.3.0-M25.jar and I got this error:

***IntroSpec.scala:5: error: Symbol 'type org.specs2.main.ArgumentsArgs' is missing from the classpath.This symbol is required by 'trait org.specs2.specification.create.SpecificationCreation'.

Comment: `org.specs2.main.ArgumentsArgs` is in the module `specs2-common`. Anyway, it's easier to run it using a build tool. For example, sbt.

Comment: Actually I've tried to compile & run this code using sbt. Actually, this code is taken from a book called Getting Started with SBT for Scala, but the **build.sbt** just didn't work so I tried to compile this way. Now I've added **specs2-common_2.12-4.3.5.jar** and this time I got this error: IntroSpec.scala:5: error: Symbol 'type org.specs2.matcher.MustMatchers' is missing from the classpath ... (truncated)